# jQuery animate get current value from associated array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got the following code:

```js
var tot = 0;
var prices = {
  "Price1:": 37152.32,
  "Price2:": 54023,
  "Price3:": 37261.75
};
var animationDuration = 2000; // Must be lower than carousel rotation

function animatePrices() {
  var dur = animationDuration / Object.keys(prices).length;
  for (var key in prices) {
    tot += prices[key];

    $({
      p: 0
    }).animate({
      p: tot
    }, {
      duration: dur,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function(now) {
        document.getElementById("total").textContent = now.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("what-for").textContent = key + " $" + prices[key];
      }
    });
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  animatePrices();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$<span id="total"></span>
<br>
<span id="what-for"></span>
```

But as you can see, in the what-for span it shows Price3. But I want it to loop through the prices as the price goes up.
Ex:
When now is 37100 then what-for is Price1.
When now is 40000 then what-for is Price2.
When now is 100000 then what-for  Price3.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is `now` variable?

Comment: function(now) do you mean that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in you code is that it was calling `animate` inside a loop. That is messing up your the variable logic. You can use something like the following. I am using recursive call on animation end here.

```js
var tot = 0;
var prices = {
  "Price1:": 37152.32,
  "Price2:": 54023,
  "Price3:": 37261.75
};
var pricesArray = Object.keys(prices);
var animationDuration = 20000; // Must be lower than carousel rotation
var dur = animationDuration / pricesArray.length;
function animatePrices() {
  key = pricesArray.shift();
  start = tot;
  tot += prices[key];
  if(!key)
    return false;
  $({
    p: start
  }).animate({
    p: tot
  }, {
    duration: dur,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function(now) {
      $("#total").text(now.toFixed(2));
      $("#what-for").text(key + " $" + prices[key]);
    },
    done: animatePrices
  });
}

window.onload = animatePrices;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$<span id="total"></span>
<br>
<span id="what-for"></span>
```

Comment: It seems that the counter restarts upon change of the what-for change.

Answer (score 0):

If you like,  added a ratio for each animation in Rejith R Krishnan code.

I changed the object associated array though, to :

```
var prices = [
  37152.32,
  54023,
  37261.75
];
```

and the ratios :

```
var ratios=[];
for(var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++){
    ratios[i]=prices[i]/total;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a6k9w9k7/